# Animating a marker pin on Bing Maps for Metro apps

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, bing-maps

I have a Bing Map control and I want to animate the location of a pin drawn on the map.

Ideally I'd want to write code like this:

```cs
// Image myPin = some Image on the map layer;

var sb = new Storyboard();
var duration = DurationHelper.FromTimeSpan(System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
sb.Duration = duration;

LocationAnimation ani = new LocationAnimation();
ani.To = new Location(33.3, 11.1); // destination lat, lng
ani.Duration = duration;

sb.Children.Add(ani);
Storyboard.SetTarget(ani, myPin);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(ani, "MapLayer.Position");

Resources.Add("moveMyPin", sb);
sb.Begin();
```

Of course there is no `LocationAnimation` class in the framework. There are a couple similar: `PointAnimation` works with the `Point` type, while `DoubleAnimation` works with individual `double` values.

I assumed I have to implement my `Timeline`-derived class but the documentation I found so far is not helpful in this regard and I don't know where to start.

How to animate a property for which there is no *Animation class ready? Am I missing something?

**Update**: I *think* I can do something like

```cs
// let aniX and aniY be two DoubleAnimation objects
StoryBoard.SetTargetProperty(aniX, "(MapLayer.Position).Latitude")
StoryBoard.SetTargetProperty(aniY, "(MapLayer.Position).Longitude")
```

but now I have another problem as I don't see how to animate the attached property and always get an exception like "Cannot resolve TargetProperty (MapLayer.Position).Latitude on specified object."

So I guess the question now becomes: *how to specify a property path for an attached property?*

**Further update**: I may be on a wrong lead with the "SetTargetProperty" thing as that would make a *dependent animation* (see link in comments). Could there be a better way to animate a marker pin to a coordinate destination?

**Update 3**: as Jared pointed out I could try to animate `RenderTransform`, or use a transition to achieve my result. I had already gone this way and it doesn't seem to be my solution. This is what I found out:

- Using `RepositionThemeAnimation`, it seems I have to give the new pixel position of the pin. This is problematic for a couple reasons: first, I know the lat/lng destination of the pin, but would have to work out the projection (as far as I can tell there is no public interface to work with projection). Secondly the projection itself can change as the map zooms/pans. The pixel destination at the time of the end of the animation could not be the same as the initial pixel destination. In my scenario it's a major problem as it's very likely the map is moving while the animation is occurring.
- Using `RepositionThemeTransition` all the weird pixel/projection problems went away. It's the only way so far I was able to see the animation I expected. I just set the transition and set the new lat/lng position of the tag (via MapLayer.SetPosition). It has two major problems though. I can't set the duration (nor the easing functions) for the animation. And most importantly I can see no way to execute code when the pin gets to its final position.

Comment: It must be pointed out that what I'm trying to do turns out to be a "dependent animation", so it wouldn't benefit from hardware acceleration. I got it to partially work with a custom UserControl with Latitude/Longitude properties, but it's way too slow to be useful. Maybe there's another way to get this working.
Further discussion on MSDN [Metro app dev forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/eedbc6a1-6f31-47a0-87d3-18152dc4a6c2) and [Bing Maps for Metro dev forums](http://bit.ly/LtECZQ).

Comment: this is what I did to animate bing maps in silverlight http://www.earthware.co.uk/blog/index.php/2010/06/bing-maps-silverlight-smooth-zoom-skydive-animation/
using DependencyProperties, hopfuly it will point you in the right direction

Comment: If you fancy contributing, there's an Open Source project that extends the Bing Maps metro control here: https://github.com/carlospuk/metromapmanager

Answer (score 1):

Attached properties can be animated, but you must enclose their names in parenthesis. See an example here:

http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2007/09/080231.html

However, I believe this only works for setting the whole value (Location) and potentially not sub properties (Latitude and Longitude).

I'm wondering if you can provide more information about what you're trying to do. Is this a temporary animation? i.e. are you wanting the pin to animate in on entrance or departure? If so you can just do an animation on the RenderTransform X and Y instead. You won't actually be changing the location of the pin but you can use the RenderTransform to temporarily change where it's being drawn.

Even better, you might be able to get away with the free animations now built into the framework. You don't even need a storyboard to use them, you just set them right on the element like this:

```
<Button Content="Transitioning Button">
     <Button.Transitions>
         <TransitionCollection> 
             <EntranceThemeTransition/>
         </TransitionCollection>
     </Button.Transitions>
</Button>
```

For more examples of the animation library and even video previews for many of the animations, see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452703.aspx

Comment: There are two distinct scenarios in which I wanted to animate the Position property. Think of them like this: 1) I want a marker to travel from a source to a destination on a line; 2) I want a marker to appear as "flowing out" from another marker in a set location and moving to another location.

I had already tried with RepositionThemeAnimation and with RenderTransform. I'll post my findings in an "Update 3" to the main question as this "answer" space is limited.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, man, your problem isn't related to Bing Maps. It's related to dependency properties that can't be animated UNLESS you specify that they can. Here's how: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-animated-pie-slice.html

That link in the other answer with Charles' site is not up to date.

Comment: Jerry, this was already mentioned in one of the comments. A dependent animation is not a viable solution because it's way too slow.

Comment: Slow, huh? I wonder if you are animating too many things at once or too many properties at once. Would you nudge your UI a little to show fewer items at once or animate a few less at once?